# Finding Bases for Ker(T) and Image(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

I need a little help.

$T$:$\mathbb{R^{2x2}}\to \mathbf{P_{3}}$, of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$$->(a-b)+(a-d)x+(b-c)x^{2}+(c-d)x^{3}$

Will the basis for the $Ker({T})$ be in the form: $T\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, and $Image({T})$ = $({1, x, x^2, x^3})$ ?

If so, $T\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ = ${1+x}$

$T\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ = ${-1+x^2}$

$T\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ = ${-x^2+x^3}$

$T\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ = ${-x-x^3}$, these linear equations result in the matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&-1\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$  The leading one columns represent the span of the basis of the original matrix for $Image({T})$ = $({1+x, -1+x^2, -x^2+-x^3})$

Is the basis for the $Ker({T})$ = $(\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&d\end{bmatrix})$, where d is any number because it is a free variable in the matrix? I don't think that is right, but I am not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix of the linear transformation has rank $3$ and the first three columns are linearly independent, so you have correctly found a basis of the image.

The kernel has dimension $1$. You can find a basis from the echelon form, considering it to represent a homogeneous linear system. The equations are
\begin{cases}
x_1=x_4\\
x_2=x_4\\
x_3=x_4
\end{cases}
so a vector in the null space of the matrix has the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
d\\d\\d\\d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which corresponds to saying that
$$
\ker T=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}d&d\\d&d\end{bmatrix}\;\middle|\;d\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

The set you mentioned is not a subspace.